# Change email workflow in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

If a user wants to change to a new email address, I use:

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, newEmail);
```

...and send a confirmation mail which includes this change token. The user clicks the link in the email, arrives back at the site, and now I need to change the email.

BUT, I don't know the new email address.

I've gone through the hassle of an confirmation mail loop, so I want to use it. Asking for the email again risks mistypings that could lock out the user from his account, and is also another hurdle for the user, and more code to maintain for me.

Obvious solutions:

- ask for it again (and risk mistypings, and make the mail loop pointless)
- store the new email address in `User.NewEmailTemp` (yuck, want to keep this stateless)
- include it in the link in the email (bad security!)

There may be a better way. The change token includes a bunch of data, including a *"purpose"* which contains the new email address. Can I somehow extract/decode the purpose, or is it mangled as part of a hashing process?

Comment: Some probably irrelevant background for my system: 1) username is email address, 2) uses JWTs rather than cookies, 3) SPA (angular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply to persist it. Stateless isn't really an option. However, that doesn't mean you need to necessarily pollute the user subdomain with it. You can, for example, create a separate entity like `EmailChangeRequest`, with props for the new email, the token, and probably a timestamp (mostly for pruning/expiration). The token, here, wouldn't be for validation, but rather for lookup, so it could be considered a key on the table.

Long and short, when the user clicks the link, you look up the request via the token, get the new email from that, and then call `ChangeEmailAsync` with that new email and the token.

If you're really opposed to persistence of any sort, I've toyed around personally with a JWT-esque approach previously. I say "-esque" because passing around a full encrypted and signed JWT as a query or route param is going to make for *extremely* long URLs for your confirmation links, perhaps even approach request limits. What I did instead, was chop off the header of the JWT, since the header is mostly meant for cross-client communication. In this scenario, I can safely assume an encryption method and issuer and such is unnecessary.

Another change I made was to use TOTP-style tokens instead of the encrypted hashes used by default. This serves to further reduce the JWT token size, and since I'm encrypting the JWT itself, it's not that important if the token inside is encrypted itself. The token provider for things like email confirmation can be [easily customized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tokens) in `ConfigureServices`, and there's [built-in TOTP token providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.tokenoptions.defaultemailprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that can be used, so this is also relatively low-friction.

I still don't think it's necessarily a bad thing to persist it, especially if you use a separate entity outside of your user subdomain. However, the pseudo JWT approach might fit your needs better if you don't want to go that route.

Comment: So many good ideas here... many thanks! The separate table is a decent quick-fix, but the little-JWT idea just feels better.

Comment: What I don't understand is why they didn't bolt-on the email to the change token, as part of a signed header, rather than encode it into the payload. It would have been so much more useful that way as it would be secure from tampering but reveal the crucial bit of info that we need in this workflow. And I see the 3.0 code they've just written doesn't do it that way. So your approach is probably the bet we're gonna get.

Comment: I think the idea there is that it's still exposed. Only the payload is protected. The header has to be readable to all clients to negotiate encryption and verification of signing token. If it's exposed at all, then it might as well be exposed entirely - obfuscation is not security - so such an approach would be no better than just tacking to the URL.

Comment: True but the way I was thinking is that the mail loop ensures the user owns that mail, and wants to perform the change. So after that I'm not too worried about sending the address in cleartext, I just want to know that it cannot be tampered with in transit. Agreed though that there are even more secure ways, like you've highlighted, but the way I was thinking was stateless, reasonably secure, known to be accurate (because I encoded it), and easy... but can't be done from what I can tell.

Comment: Well, it can be done by you. If that's how you want to handle it, there's nothing stopping you from implementing it that way.

Comment: Hey Chris, I took these ideas and implemented a little-jwt without the header, etc... and it worked! Then I discovered `userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, newEmail, token)` does in fact *compare the new email to the one in the hash*! So we can send the email address as part of the GET request's querystring, and it'll be verified appropriately without compromising security or risking human error! So this question was a massive waste of time, and I'm sorry for dragging you into it! :-) What should I do about this question given that it's obsolete (still lots of good ideas in here...)?

Comment: I think the only reason this problem and possible solutions are still valuable is for the case the dev is paranoid to send the new email in cleartext. But that is a very low risk problem as the email is not a secret, and it will be verified at the server before the change (tamper-proof and no MITM attack).

Comment: There's more than just simple security to take into account. There's also PII. However, I agree that that is also fairly minimal, though with some of the crazy legislation coming out of the EU like GDPR, who knows. As for your question, just leave it.

Comment: Thanks for your help regardless, was a learning experience! :-)